# How do Bitconnect Creators Hide their Identity?

Tags: bitconnect-coin

[Does government really seize Bitconnect assets?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76353/does-government-really-seize-bitconnect-assets/76374?noredirect=1#comment88650_76374)

This asks if Governments really seize bitconnect assets.

There are a bunch of legal arguments.

However, with all legal arguments aside, is there anything governments can do to nail the creator of bitconnect ponzy?

It seems that no body knows who created bitconnect. They are invincible.

But how come?

Their website is accessible openly. How did they pay for their website that allows them to host anonymously? Do they pay with bitcoin too?

What did the silkroad do "wrong" that bitconnect did "right"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the data used for the domain registration.

https://domainbigdata.com/bitconnect.co

By quick look, they did good job not to be traceable.
Maybe you can find something in it. You may have to complain to Panama government for allowing this.

What did Silkroad wrong? Was openly laughing to government challenging their war on drugs. The state wanted to shut it down. Bitconnect on the other hand stole money from foolish investors buying cryptocurrencies, that actually work in states favor. They would never care the same way as in case on SilkRoad.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. I think the trick here is even if the investor uses wire, the cops will still not caught the culprit. Governments are lazy when it comes to enforcing crimes that's not actually victimless.

Comment: Does namecheap requires credit card of bitcoin to pay? Can people use namecheap to register domain anonymously?

Comment: Namecheap does not seem to be accepting crypto payments at all. If the police would request the data on people having the Bitconnect domain, Namecheap would most likely provide it. But even if you pay using credit card there are ways to remain anonymous, not sure about level of namecheap verification, but I guess you can use prepaid credit card, card details bought from darknet, etc...The options are there.

Answer (score 1):

> **How do Bitconnect Creators Hide their Identity?**

By using services† that either do not ask their customers for identification or which do not adequately verify proffered identification.

By paying for those services using payment methods which are anonymous, or at least pseudonymous (e.g. Bitcoin, pre-pay debit-cards, fiat cash, ...).

---

† domain-registrars, web-hosting, ISPs etc

Comment: such as? I think I would need to know the host they used, the domain registrars they use, and the web hosting they used

Comment: The usual simple methods find Namecheap Inc and Cloudflare.